# How can i concat a string with the value from terminal?

Tags: makefile

Below is my makefile

```
LATEST_GIT_COMMIT_HASH := $(shell git rev-parse HEAD | cut -c1-8)

docker:
    @echo "\n" &&\
    read -p "Please enter a version number (ex: 0001): " release_vesion &&\
    echo $$release_vesion_${LATEST_GIT_COMMIT_HASH}
```

I try to concat the release_version from my input and the git version number then print them out.

But it seem not working.

How to concat the string with input value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash you need to use `${var_name}concat_some_more_text`, the braces seperate the variable from the rest of the concatented string. Eg:

```
    var_name=bob
    echo "1: $var_nameconcat_some_more_text"
    echo "2: ${var_name}concat_some_more_text"
```

returns:

```
    1:
    2: bobconcat_some_more_text
```

So your code should look like:

```
LATEST_GIT_COMMIT_HASH := $(shell git rev-parse HEAD | cut -c1-8)

docker:
    @echo "\n" &&\
    read -p "Please enter a version number (ex: 0001): " release_vesion &&\
    echo "release ver: $$release_vesion" ; \
    echo "$${release_vesion}_$(LATEST_GIT_COMMIT_HASH)"
```

In make use `$${...}` for bash variable (you have correctly used the double $ but not the braces) and `$(...)` for make variables. You don't always need the braces for the bash variable but when concatenating the variable name to another string like you are then you do need them to separate them.